# Hive SQL - select all rows containing a value; where one of the rows matches a specific value

Tags: sql, hive

I have a Hive table like this -

```
Name     ..... Page
Sid ...........Login
Sid ...........Buy 
Nancy ......Home
Nancy ......Register
Nancy ......Buy
```

I'd like to extract all the rows for Name where one of the Names has a Page=login. So, it would extract two rows for for name=Sid but no rows for name=Nancy.

I tried -

```
select * from table where name in (select name from table where page='login');
```

However, I get the error -

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 1:142 Unsupported SubQuery Expression ''login'': SubQuery expression refers to Outer query expressions only.
```

Can anyone help? This query seems simple enough. Thanks

Comment: Your error is rather strange.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Hi, the real data is NDA I'm afraid.

Comment: [Sid and Nancy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFjb_p_5DVAhVI7YMKHeR0DGIQFgg9MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt0091954%2F&usg=AFQjCNEIPWeoPdbdbOpLzJbMmLuGnygQ1w)?  Am I dating myself here?

Answer (score 0):

The following query would work anywhere ANSI SQL is supported:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Name
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Page = 'login' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name
```

The basic strategy is to do aggregation for each name, count the number of times where `login` appears as a page, and then retain only those names which meet your criteria.

Comment: Thanks for this, afraid I don't get any results when I substitute the real table names for your code; I can't share the real data as it's under NDA. I'll play around with this some more.

Comment: @BobbyKing Test the subquery in isolation and see if it returns the correct matching names.  If even that doesn't work, then maybe my approach won't work with Hive SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(case when page = 'login' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name) as numlogins
      from t
     ) t
where numlogins > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at this : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause
This is a tutorial for Hive SQL SubQueries